# Redux Dev tools doesn't show the initial state

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I am working on front-end authentication. I can register just fine, however, I realized that the dev tools show

```
null(pin):undefined
```

I could see the state just fine before, when I first created the initialState. I haven't changed anything specific to that, I just added the register function, reducers, etc. Here's the related code:

authSlice:

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import authService from "./authService";
//Get user from localStorage
const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));

const initialState = {
  user: user ? user : null,
  isError: false,
  isSuccess: false,
  isLoading: false,
  message: "",
};

// Register user

export const register = createAsyncThunk(
  "auth/register",
  async (user, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
        return await authService.register(user)
    } catch (error) {
        const message = (error.response && error.response.data && error.response.data.message) || error.message || error.toString()
        return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message)
    }
  }
);

export const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "auth",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    reset: (state) => {
      state.isLoading = false;
      state.isSuccess = false;
      state.isError = false;
      state.message = "";
    },
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
     builder
       .addCase(register.pending, (state) => {
         state.isLoading = true;
       })
       .addCase(register.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
         state.isLoading = false;
         state.isSuccess = true;
         state.user = action.payload;
       })
       .addCase(register.rejected, (state, action) => {
         state.isLoading = false;
         state.isError = true;
         state.message = action.payload;
         state.user = null;
       });
  },
});
export const { reset } = authSlice.actions;
export default authSlice.reducer;
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import App from './App';
import { store } from './app/store';



const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Register function in Register page:

```
export default function SignUp() {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    username: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
    password2: "",
  });
  const { username, email, password, password2 } = formData;

  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const { user, isLoading, isError, isSuccess, message } = useSelector(
    (state) => state.auth
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isError) {
      toast.error(message);
    }

    if (isSuccess || user) {
      navigate("/");
    }

    dispatch(reset());
  }, [user, isError, isSuccess, message, navigate, dispatch]);

  const onChange = (e) => {
    setFormData((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    }));
  };

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (password !== password2) {
      toast.error("Passwords do not match");
    } else {
      const userData = {
        username,
        email,
        password,
      };
      dispatch(register(userData));
    }
  };
```

Edited:

works fine before registering(cleared cache from browser to 'logout')
[image]

As soon as I go to the register page, the info is gone on the dev tools, as well as after the registration. However, I did see the actions before, now they are gone as well.

[image]

Comment: So *what*, or *where*, exactly is the issue? I think we'll need a bit more context here for what specifically you are looking at and where you are looking at it.

Comment: @DrewReese I should be seeing the initial state in dev tools like this:user : null,
  isError: false,
  isSuccess: false,
  isLoading: false,
  message: "",
But it says state is undefined

Comment: Can you [edit] the post to provide a quality screen capture of the redux-devtools open and showing the dispatched actions and the current state value?

Comment: @DrewReese sure, will be updating soon

Comment: Hit cmd/ctrl + R in the dev-tool window to refresh it. Also, in the "select" drop down ensure you've selected the correct redux store "instance" to inspect.

Comment: @DrewReese Refreshing didn't help. Also there are so states to choose from in the select drop down

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250862/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-suleyman-eminbyli).

Comment: Since it seems you've confirmed the redux-devtool is working again from [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/55785787#55785787) I'm voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo".